# Gmail Script/Add on Stackdriver logs are missing

Tags: stackdriver, gmail-addons

I am debugging a gmail addon that I created and I use console.log to get back debugging information. It prints the information out into stackdriver's log viewer, but I'm having an issue where logs are not showing up.

The addon reaching a page that I know for a fact is after a log would have been executed, but the log never appears.

I'll reload the addon and it will do the same sequence twice and sometimes some logs will show up and other times none will.

I don't see any error messages and I can't find any other examples of this happening, but it has been making debugging incredibly difficult because I can't output the data I need to understand what is happening as it is consistently failing to appear in the log viewer.

If anyone has any idea why this is happening or work arounds to make it start working I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide your current script which can be reproduced your issue? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I removed all my console logs and re-added them manually and it seems to be working now. I'm thinking one was improperly structured and made all subsequent ones not work? It is difficult to know though as the issue has stopped.